# rich:tabPanel and problems when field has required="true"

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

Let's consider following, simplified example:

We have 2 tabs withing `<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">`, each tab has `<h:inputText value="" required="true" />` and at the moment we want to switch from one tab to another, and the inputText is empty (we don't want to submit value from it anyway, we want to go to another tab) we get `"Validation Error: Value is required."`

The example code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
 >
        <a4j:form id="mainForm"
            reRender="mainForm"
            ajaxSubmit="true">

            <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
                <rich:tab label="TabA" >
                    <a4j:region>
                        <h:outputText value="Tab A content" />
                        <h:inputText value="" required="true" />
                    </a4j:region>
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab label="TabB">
                    <a4j:region>
                        <h:outputText value="Tab B content" />
                        <h:inputText value="" required="true" />
                    </a4j:region>
                </rich:tab>
            </rich:tabPanel>
            <rich:messages />
        </a4j:form>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "immediate" attribute to the tabPanel. To quote the [docs](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf?tab=info&cid=12221364) this means that the tabPanel:

> "...component value must be converted and
>   validated immediately (that is, during
>   Apply Request Values phase), rather
>   than waiting until a Process
>   Validations phase"

For example:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" immediate="true">
```